# Many to Many return childrens with same parent

Tags: t-sql

Perhaps I do not see the forest for the trees but I have following challenge.
There is a many to many relationship:

```
    Table A   1:n     Table B   n:1     Table C
    id_A              id_B              id_C
                      id_A (FK)
                      id_C (FK)
```

Data

```
       A1              B1                  C1
                       A1
                       C1

       A1              B2                  C2
                       A1
                       C2

       A1              B4                  C3
                       A1
                       C3

       A2              B3                  C1
                       A2
                       C1
```

Now suppose I have two id_C's (C1 and C2) and must find those records from table A that reference both id_C. Those that don't match both id_C should not be in the result. So, the result for above example should be only A1.

Please help.
Regards
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id_A 
from table b 
where id_C = 'c1' 
intersect 
select id_A 
from table b 
where id_C = 'c2'
```